# Error using fzero() with negative values

Tags: matlab

I have the following function:

```
function f = graph1(x)
     f = sqrt(x) - cos(sqrt(x));
end
```

Calling fzero for it via:

```
>> x1 =fzero(@graph1, [-1.0,1.0])
```

And have an error:

```
Error using fzero (line 242)
Function values at interval endpoints must be finite and real.
```

All works fine with positive values, what's wrong?

P.S I'm new in matlab.

Comment: The error is pretty self explanatory, the values of `f` at your boundaries (`[-1.0, 1.0]`) must be finite and real. `sqrt(x)` is not real for negative numbers.

Comment: Thank you I understand my mistake, problem in math not in code :)
How to mark your comment as answer?

Comment: You're welcome, I'll post an answer in a moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said above, the error is more or less self-explanatory. Your function is not finite and real at your interval endpoints because `sqrt(x)` is not real for negative `x` values.